# combo box fails to populate both fields in the associated form

Tags: database, winforms, ms-access, combobox

I have a single combo box which selects data from a table called Roster.  It chooses all Scout_ID's and Full_names and displays them so the user can choose a record to enter data against.

I am not sure how much detail you would like, but the basic problem is that the combo box populates the key field (Scout_ID) but fails to populate the Full_name field on the same form.

The interesting thing is that different form uses the same technique, however, it populates both ID and Name perfectly. I have been working with Microsoft support for a week and they can't explain it either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: And exactly what is the technique? Why would you expect a combobox to populate two fields? Like any data control, it can be bound to only 1 field. Requires code (macro or VBA) to populate other field. If you simply want to display the fullname in a textbox, then ControlSource expression can reference combobox column by index. Should not be saving the full name. That is duplicating data.

Comment: Interesting that you should say that, as I pointed out in Paragraph 3, another form combo box populates both fields on its associated form.   I can not find a difference between the two forms other than the form they populate?   if you have a better way to do this I am willing to try it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing that macro with me?  The combo box simply is a look-up for all the kids names and the key field that identifies them uniquely, eg. Scout_ID the combo box select the boys ID and his name.

Comment: In VBA simply: `Me.Full_name = Me.comboboxName.Column(1)`, column index begins with 0 so if name is in second column, index is 1. The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into, possibly the combobox AfterUpdate. But again, why are you even saving the full name? There must be some code in the other form that is saving the second value because a combobox can be bound to only one field.

Comment: Check the properties of the Full_name field on that different form, especially the ControlSource property. If that field is based on a field of the form's datasource query, check that query, it might contain a "lookup-join" on the Scouts table.

Comment: The two fields are needed as the Scout_ID is meaningless to the person entering the data, but the Scout_ID is the Table key that has all other information stored against.  That 23487654233  said  is meaningless.  BUT "23487654233  Dick Patton" allows choosing the correct person.    I will try both of your ideas!

Comment: WolfgangK, the Control Source is Full_Name, however, it is populated on the fly at the time of entry **"Full_Name [Roster_Master]![first_name]" & " " & [Roster_Master]![middle_name] & " " & [Roster_Master]![last_name] & " " & [Roster_Master]![Suffix] **    Perhaps this helps?

Comment: The VB Command works like a charm!  Thank you!